# Can't read json file via Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

Trying to test out Athena on a sample JSON file (~90MB). I've put the file in the S3, and tried the following:

- Used Amazon Glue to crawl the folder in which the JSON file sits. Everything seemed to work in order, but when I tried to query on Athena, I got "Internal Error"
- After some research, I figured that this is probably due to incorrect schema detection, so removed all the fields except 1; this time the query ran, but the results were all empty
- Tried creating the table through the `manual` option in Athena, again focusing on getting just 1 column to work - same empty results
- Tried running a manual DDL statement to create the table - same empty results
- Tried playing with the encryption setting - same empty results

My JSON file is newline delimited (e.g. each new line is a single JSON object) - that's how I understood it should work.

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found a solution?

Comment: Can you show your json schema? I would recommend creating table manually by using CREATE TABLE command

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Glue set up my tables with what looks like a desired, valid schema based on the JSON files in S3 but I get "zero results" when I query from Athena.

Comment: Unfortunately no - this was a part of a very time-limited POC to see if I can get this to work (which I couldn't out-of-the-box) so I did not pursue...